# fontspec in book title

Tags: titles, chapters, fontspec, books

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
    \part{title}
    \chapter{\fontspec{Latin Modern Roman} chapter title}
    \part{title}
    \chapter{title}
\end{document}
```

I use package **fontspec** to switch font from one to another. As in this code, I want to typeset the chapter title using font **Latin Modern Roman**. Actually, it works fine with **report** and **memoir** class. But it produce an error in **book** class. How can I fix it?

Comment: I suspect a missing `\protect` just before `\fontspec`, i.e. `\protect\fontspec`, but I can't test right now, since I get errors on the missing font

Comment: Do you want to have all chapter heading to look different/have another font? There are packages giving you an interface to define such stuff globally.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I tried to add it, but still not work!

Comment: @Johannes_B I want another font!

Comment: For all (globally?) or just one?

Comment: @Johannes_B Actually, I want a global one, but it is better if we can change only one.

Comment: What error do you get? This compiles file for me. (`fontspec` uses LM as standard anyway, so there is no actual font change here.)

Comment: @JosephWright It produced error like this **line 6: fontspec error: "font-not-found"! THe font "LATIN MODERN ROMAN" cannot be found. \part** . It produced pdf file but take longer time than usual.

Comment: @JosephWright Note that the error I gave above is obtained from my IDE, **TeXstudio**. For the build-in editor, **TeXworks**, it produced **l.6 \part {title}?** and when I typed **h** for help it showed me like this **A font might not be found for many reasons. Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc. When in doubt, ask someone for help!**

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you just want to have a serif font instead of the sans-serif one? Or do you want to use another font in the main Document and LMR in the headings? Are you using xelatex or lualatex?

Comment: @MaxNoe Frankly, I want the body text, section title, chapter title, and part title in different fonts.

Comment: you can make it work but it is _always_ wrong to put formatting instructions in a section heading. It is supposed to just have text which can be set in several contexts, the heading itself, the page head, the table of contents etc. The argument should just have text and the fonts used in each context should be set by the class

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see! So I should choose another way to fix it. Maybe memoir class or scrbook class is better to customize all of those stuffs.

Comment: I updated my answer to provide different fonts

Answer (score 4):

## Using the `scrbook`-class of KOMA-Script:

Serif-Font in all headings (chapter, section, etc.)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello World}
Test
\end{document}
```

Or explicitly set the font with fontspec:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\headingsfont}{Latin Modern Roman}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\headingsfont}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello World}
Test
\end{document}
```

The result is identical if the standard serif font is Latin Modern Roman, you can set this with `\setromanfont{<fontname>}`:

[image: result]

If you just want to change certain structure elements use e.g. `\addtokomafont{chapter}{}` or `\addtokomafont{section}{}` etc:

```
\documentclass[open=any]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Pagella}
\newfontfamily{\partnumfont}{Comic Sans MS}
\newfontfamily{\partfont}{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily{\chapterfont}{Tex Gyre Chorus}
\newfontfamily{\sectionfont}{Tex Gyre Heros}    
\usepackage{xcolor}

\addtokomafont{partnumber}{\color{red}\partnumfont}
\addtokomafont{part}{\partfont}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\chapterfont}
\addtokomafont{section}{\sectionfont}}

\begin{document}
\part{Test}
\section{my first Koma-Script book}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Using the standard `book` class and package `titlesec`:

You probably need to adjust the settings.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Pagella}
\newfontfamily{\partfont}{Tex Gyre Heros}
\newfontfamily{\chapterfont}{Tex Gyre Chorus}
\newfontfamily{\sectionfont}{Tex Gyre Heros}        
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\part}[display]{\partfont\Huge\bfseries\centering}{\partname\ \thepart}{20pt}{}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\chapterfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{20pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\sectionfont\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{20pt}{}

\begin{document}
\part{Test}
\chapter{Hello Worl.}
\section{standard book}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

Comment: The preferred way to choose a font using `fontspec` is to use `\newfontfamily` etc. and not to use the `\fontspec` command directly.  See §5 of the `fontspec` manual.

Comment: ok, i changed it :)

Comment: I see! We can change it for **memoir** and **scrbook**. So this means that we don have such options to do in **book** class, right?

Comment: simple options? No. Packages that implement solutions? Yes. Documentclasses that implement simple options? Yes.

Comment: @MaxNoe What are the packages? and what are the document classes beside memoir and scrbook?

Comment: I'll add a solution for book and the titlespec package.

Answer (score 2):

I used the `xpatch` package to hook into the command for typesetting the chapter head. This will change the font for all chapters.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec,xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\normalfont}{\fontspec{Latin Modern Roman}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \part{title}
    \chapter{chapter title}
    \part{title}
    \chapter{title}
\end{document}
```

We can use this solution to easily adjust the font per chapter

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec,xpatch}
\newcommand*\setchapterfont[1]{\xdef\chapterfont{#1}}
\setchapterfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\normalfont}{\fontspec\chapterfont}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\setchapterfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\chapter{Test 1}
\setchapterfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\chapter{Test 2}
\setchapterfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\chapter{Test 3}
\end{document}
```

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

## With `memoir`

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec,blindtext}
\newcommand*\setchapterfont[2][]{
  \renewcommand*\chapnamefont{\huge\bfseries\fontspec[#1]{#2}}
  \renewcommand*\chapnumfont{\huge\bfseries\fontspec[#1]{#2}}
  \renewcommand*\chaptitlefont{\Huge\bfseries\fontspec[#1]{#2}}
}
\newcommand*\setsectionfont[2][]{
  \setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\fontspec[#1]{#2}}
}
\newcommand*\setsubsectionfont[2][]{
  \setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\fontspec[#1]{#2}}
}
\newcommand*\setsubsubsectionfont[2][]{
  \setsubsubsecheadstyle{\normalsize\bfseries\fontspec[#1]{#2}}
}
\begin{document}
\setchapterfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\setsectionfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Cursor}
\setsubsectionfont[Color=009911]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsubsubsectionfont{Raleway}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works. Anyway, what are the command for changing the part and section?

Comment: @OLSAY If you want to change all of your headings this isn't a suitable approach. You should look into the packages `titlesec` or the `scrbook` or the `memoir` documentclass. I will provide an example for `memoir`.

Comment: What is the solution? If we have a better solution by using **memoir** class, I think I should change to use it.

Comment: @OLSAY See the updated answer. You can now also specify extra font feature in square brackets.

Comment: The preferred way to choose a font using `fontspec` is to use `\newfontfamily` etc. and not to use the `\fontspec` command directly.  See §5 of the `fontspec` manual.

Comment: This works just as well with only [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox), for what it's worth.